# Can we change the text of a permission in android

Tags: android, android-permissions

I know this sounds silly and also not a technical question, but, I think, its important to know and SO is the best place. I have searched abit before posting here.

Can we change the text of the permission?

Let's say I am using a permission, "GET_ACCOUNTS". This will display, "Your Accounts" and "Discover known accounts", to the user when he installs the application. Let's say I want to inform the user, that this permission is only being used for "push notifications" and hence i want to change this to, "Used for Push Notifications" instead of "Discover known accounts". Can i do this?

I know if this is permitted, developer can write what ever they want, but, in a good sense, this will clear up the doubts that most users have while installing the application.

Thanks for your help..

Comment: I sure don't hope so. However benignant your own intentions may be, it would allow for more sinister developers to lie to users about what they're asking permission for.

Comment: Of course you can't do this.  How else would Android assure users that the permissions apps are asking for are the correct ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. However I noticed many cases where developers put in the description of their app on Google Play (somewhere at the bottom), the permissions the app require along with an explanation.

Of course there's no guarantee that all users read the app description, but, it's still a way to tell the users why do you really need those permissions.