# Can i change the appearance of the permission text?

Tags: android

Can i change the appearance of the permission text in the prompt that is showing at the time of installation.

When i try to install my app the permissions are showing in lower case letters

Comment: You cannot edit how permissions are displayed. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491344/can-we-change-the-text-of-a-permission-in-android

Comment: Thanks for the response. i just want to make sure that it is not possible.My tester has reported this as a bug.And when i checked it seems like for other apps, the permissions appear in the list as sentence case.

Comment: The tester should know that permissions are part of Android itself. You shouldn't be able to change how they are displayed or that could compromise the information/security. Google image search for "Android permissions" and you'll see some examples. They are mostly lowercase, but it seems like when the permissions are displayed in the Play Store (white window) they are uppercase, still not full sentences though.

Answer (score 1):

Well the answer is plain and simple .. NO

Comment: Some source wouldn't still hurt. :)